# Showing isomorphism between two models of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, functions, upper-lower-bounds

From Vladimir Zorich's Analysis:

> Show that if $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}'$ are two models of the set
>   of real numbers and $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}'$ is a mapping
>   such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)*f(y)$ for any $x,y \in
>  \mathbb{R}$ then $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}'$ is a bijective
>   mapping that preserves order.

**Note**: [similar question was asked on this website previously, but it had no response about the usage of potential solutions presented.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456157/isomorphism-between-two-models-of-real-numbers)

## My attempts

**Idea on injectivity**:

By definition, suppose $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x=y$, then if a transformation $f$ is injective, $f(x)=f(y)$.

In this specific case, if $x=y$, then $x+y=x+x=y+y$, therefore $f(x+y)=2f(x)=2f(y)\implies f(x) = f(y)$. Which shows that $f$ is injective as long as the assumption $2f(x)=2f(y)\implies f(x) = f(y)$ is true. Therefore $f$ is injective.

Coming from Linear Algebra, I was planning to utilize a rank-nullity theorem to show that since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}'$ are vector spaces over themselves, then $f$ must also be surjective. But unfortunately $f$ is not precisely defined to be linear, therefore I'm skipping it.

**Idea on Bijectivity/Surjectivity**:

Now that I was possibly able to show that $f$ is injective, I should either show that it is surjective or directly an isomorphism without even using the premise derived above.

I saw in the comments from the link above, that the least upper bound principle (or the axiom of completeness) is a one way that can possibly solve this.

*Finding 1*:

Suppose there be a finite set $S \subset \mathbb{R}'$, such that $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, f(r) \notin S'$. By the least upper bound principle, there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}'$ such that $c \geq s',  \forall s' \in S$, then if $c \neq \textrm{max}(S)$ (consequential assumption), it can be seen $f(x) \geq s', \forall s' \in S'$.

*Finding 2*:

Suppose $\exists r' \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, f(r) \neq r'$. Then it can be assumed that $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, f(r) > r'$ or $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}, f(r) < r'$. Therefore, by the axiom of completeness, $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}, (f(r) \geq c \geq r') \implies (f(\frac{r}{r'}) \geq c)$ or conversely, $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}, (r' \geq c \geq f(r)) \implies (c \geq f(\frac{r}{r'}))$

---

## Question

Is my assumption on idea on injectivity valid? Can my ideas in bijectivity/surjectivity section be extended to show that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Are there other ways I can show that $f$ is an isomorphism using a least upper bound principle?

Thank you!

Comment: Your definition of injectivity is wrong, it is actually the other way round: a function $f$ is injective iff $f(x)=f(y)$ ***implies*** $x=y$. You've proved that $x=y$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$, which is just how equality works.

Comment: @lisyarus What a stupid mistake... Thank you for mentioning that.